# Synapse - Get all sheet of en excel or csv and storage into data lake -

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

it's possible to get all sheet of an excel or csv and storage them into a data lake ? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the same thing in my environment. Here are the sample files in the container:

[image: Ref1]

I'm able to get all my files you can check:

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls('wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/')
```

[image: Ref2]

**Reference:**

[Configure access to ADLS Gen2 Storage account | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api)